# Как добавить value при выборе в jQuery и выполнить функцию

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код в js

```
$(function() {
        $(document).on('change', 'div.form select[name="fields[5]"]', function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value && value.charCodeAt(0) != 8212) {
                $(this).closest('div.form').find('select[name="fields[1]"]')
                    .val("GOOD").end().find('input[name="fields[2]"]')
                    .val(value)
            }
        })
    });
```

Вопрос: Как прописать в коде функции значение выбранного value в name="fields[5]", чтоб при выборе, к примеру value="1", выполнялась функция, а не просто выполнение при выборе значения, как сейчас?

Answer (score 2):

собственно решила вопросик сама....

```
if (value==1 && value.charCodeAt(0) != 8212) {
```

Comment: Второе условие содержится в первом - то есть не нужно.